# Error creating bean with name 'loginRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Here is my code:

**springboot class**

```
   package com.angularjs.app.controller;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


//@RestController
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

     protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
            return builder.sources(Application.class);
        }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
         }

}
```

**Controller**

```
    package com.angularjs.app.controller;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.angularjs.app.message.Response;
import com.angularjs.app.model.LoginVO;
import com.angularjs.app.repo.LoginRepository;
//@Configuration
//@ComponentScan
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.angularjs.app.repo")
public class LoginController {

    //@Autowired
    LoginRepository loginRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/findbyusername")
    public Response findByLastName(@RequestParam("username") String username) {

        LoginVO userDetails = loginRepository.findByUsername(username);

        return new Response("Done", userDetails);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    ModelAndView home(ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        modelAndView.setViewName("home");

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/postuserdetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void postCustomer(@RequestBody LoginVO loginVo) {

        loginRepository.save(new LoginVO(loginVo.getUsername(), loginVo.getPassword(), loginVo.getEmail(),"Y"));
    }

}
```

**response class**

```
    package com.angularjs.app.message;

public class Response {

    private String status;
    private Object data;

    public Response() {

    }

    public Response(String status, Object data) {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

**model class**

```
    package com.angularjs.app.model;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_details")
public class LoginVO implements  Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name="user_id")
    private long userId;

    @Column (name="user_name")
    private String username;

    @Column (name="valid_user")
    private String validUser;

    @Column (name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column (name="email")
    private String email;

    public LoginVO(String username, String password, String email, String validuser) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.validUser = validuser;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getValidUser() {
        return validUser;
    }

    public void setValidUser(String validUser) {
        this.validUser = validUser;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Customer[userId=%d, username='%s', email='%s']", userId, username, email);
    }

}
```

**repo class**

```
   package com.angularjs.app.repo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.angularjs.app.model.LoginVO;
@Service
public interface LoginRepository extends CrudRepository<LoginVO, Long> {

    LoginVO findByUsername(String userName);
}
```

**Exception**

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-08-25 16:23:47.591 ERROR 2702 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.angularjs.app.model.LoginVO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:740) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.angularjs.app.controller.Application.main(Application.java:21) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.angularjs.app.model.LoginVO
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:169) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:107) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:298) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You have been here long enough to know this question was not suitable for Stack Overflow. (1) Avoid txtspk and please-help begging, (2) don't ask for questions not to be closed as a duplicate, and don't add meta commentary to moderators, (3) **format your code properly** and don't expect other people to do it, (4) add statements about the problem and what you have tried to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

By adding `@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=LoginVO.class)` on Application class, my issue got resolved.